# Why is <script> not being executed on iOS if at the end of the body?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, web

This fact had driven me mad for weeks, and after several debugging and a bit of luck, I've noticed that if I put the JS code in the `<script>` tag at the **bottom** of the `<body>` it does **not** get executed on *iPhone* and *iPad*.
Just moving the code in the `<head>` fix the problem.
I've tried it on different projects, from Vanilla to Wordpress ones, so I'm pretty sure it's not coincidence.
Why is this happening ?
Hope this can help other people avoid going crazy like me.

Comment: Do you mean *after* the closing </body> tag? If so, that's not valid HTML, as far as I know. If you mean *inside* the body, but near the bottom, that should work. Perhaps your HTML is mis-formatted in some other way.

Comment: No it's inside the body, and I don't think since it's working on every single device, from Windows to Android and Mac OS except iOS - aka iPhone and iPad

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly fine for me, in a quick test with iOS 10.0.1. You may want to add more detail to your question. For reference, I put this file on my local web server:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello, StackOverflow
        <script>
            alert("Yo!");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the file loads and runs the script just fine. The alert() fires off before the page is rendered, which is the expected behavior, I think.